# FragmentTransaction replace and ActionBar Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I replace an actionbar tab with itself so that it will be completely reloaded? My current approach (which doesn't work) is to call FragmentTransaction replace with a new instance of the fragment like so:

```
AgendaFragment agenda = new AgendaFragment();
String label = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_list);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("date", date);
agenda.setArguments(bundle);
ft.replace(R.id.pager, agenda, label);
ft.commit();
```

In my agenda fragment I have an ExpandableListView which is what I want to refresh. Unfortunately, the above code doesn't reload the ExpandableListView and it remains the same. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit:** Here are the relevant snippets from `AgendaFragment`.

```
public class AgendaFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> mDate;
    Vector<List<String>> mMappedInfo;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = (Context) getActivity();
        mDate = new ArrayList<String>();
        mMappedInfo = new Vector<List<String>>();

        //...
        //Get necessary information from server.
        serverCommunication();
    }

    private void serverCommunication() {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            //get information

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                if (result) {
                    //parse data
                    apptXmlParsing(mCompleteXml);
                }

            }

        }.execute();

    }            

    public void apptXmlParsing(final XmlDom completeXml) {
        //Parse received data
        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView(){

        final ExpandableListView eLV = (ExpandableListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.expListView);

        //process data into acceptable format

        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(mContext, mDate, mMappedInfo, mCurrDate);
        eLV.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is this:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
final Tab tab = actionBar.getSelectedTab();
int selTab = actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex();
String label = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_list);
Tab agendaTab = actionBar.newTab();
agendaTab.setText(label);
TabListener<AgendaFragment> tl3 = new TabListener<AgendaFragment>(this, label,
    AgendaFragment.class, date);
agendaTab.setTabListener(tl3);

actionBar.addTab(agendaTab, selTab, true);

actionBar.removeTab(tab);
```

And in my onTabSelected method in my TabListener class:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
if(mDate != null)
    bundle.putString("date", mDate);
mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

This has the desired effect of reloading a tab with the correct date while getting rid of the old tab.